# gzip piped output into ssh command

Tags: gzip, pipe

I make backup over ssh like this:

```
mysqldump -u dbuser -pXXXXXXXX dbname | ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_backup backup@my.server.com 'cat > /var/backups/services/my_service/db/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").sql'
```

How to send gziped data to save bandwith and disk space ?

Answer (score 4):

adding this to ~/.ssh/config ssh will gzip on the fly :)

http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config for more detailed options

```
Host *
    Compression yes
    # from 1 (fast) to 9 (slow, best). The default level is 6
    # CompressionLevel 9
    # ServerAliveInterval 15
    # ServerAliveCountMax 3
    # KeepAlive yes

Host bak-serv
    Hostname my.server.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_backup
    User backup
    # Port 22
```

with your command, you get a sql.gz at the end not a plain sql text file.

```
mysqldump -u dbuser -pXXXXXXXX dbname \
  | gzip | cat | ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_backup backup@my.server.com \
  'cat > /var/backups/services/my_service/db/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").sql.gz'
```

becomes

```
mysqldump -u dbuser -pXXXXXXXX dbname \
   | ssh bak-serv \
   | gzip -c > /var/backups/services/my_service/db/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").sql.gz
```